# Диапазон ввода чисел

Tags: python

В python'e новичок. Прошу помощи. Само условие:

> Вводятся два целых числа A и B. –215 <
> A < B < 215.  Вывести сумму
> последовательности A, A+1, A+2, …,
> B-2, B-1, B.
>
> Пример ввода: 1 3 Пример вывода: 6

Вопрос следующий: как сделать ограничение ввода чисел в диапазоне –215 < A < B < 215

Сделал велосипед, но выглядит он не кошерно. Можно ли как-то проще реализовать?

```
lownum = -215
highnum = 215

a = input('Input A: \n')
if a < lownum:
     print('Error. Min a = -215')
else:
    b = input('Input B: \n')
if b > highnum:
    print('Error. Max a = 215')
else:
    if a < b:
        x = sum(range(a,b+1))
        res = 'Result >> ' + str(x)
        print(res)
    else:
        print('Input Error')
```

Comment: А кошерно -- это как? Я подправил на свой вкус, но особой разницы не вижу:

    lownum,highnum = -215, 215
    while True:
        a = int(input('Input A:'))
        if a < lownum :
            print('Error. Min A = -215')
            continue
        b = int(input('Input B:')))
        if b > highnum :
            print('Error. Max B = 215')
            continue
        if a < b : break
        else :
            print('Input Error')
            exit()
    x = sum(range(a, b+1))
    print ('Result >> ' + str(x))

Кстати, у Вас, как я понимаю, python2

Comment: Много else смотрелись страшновато. Кошерно хотелось именно так, как вы поправили. Ибо у меня с применением continue и break не получалось сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Питон позволяет объединять условия `low < A < B < hi`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
low, hi = -215, 215
while True:
    s = input('Enter space-separated A, B '
              '({low} < A < B < {hi}): '.format_map(vars()))
    try:
        A, B = map(int, s.split())
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        if low < A < B < hi:
            break
        print('Try again')
print('Result:', sum(range(a, b+1)))
```

Comment: Я бы `sum(...)` заменил на `(A + B)(B - A + 1) / 2`.

Comment: @dzhioev: разрешённый диапазон очень маленький, поэтому `sum(range(a, b+1)))` достаточно эффективно, проще, понятнее и меньше шансов ошибку  совершить.  Для больших диапазонов можно `(a+b)*(b+1-a) // 2`  использовать (обратите внимание на `int` деление) в противном случае можно неверный результат получить из-за потери точности с float.

Comment: до каких пор стоит считать диапазон маленьким? Зачем писать заведомо неэффективный код, если можно использовать всем известную формулу уровня средней школы? Про деление верно заметили, я просто не обратил внимание, что про 3-ий Python идет речь.

Comment: @dzhioev: premature optimization is the root of all evil

Comment: да знаю я, но это не тот случай (IMHO).

Comment: @dzhioev: это именно тот случай, потому что читатель, интересующийся как с `if` работать, чтобы диапазон проверить, скопирует вашу формулу как есть и молча получит неверный результат для больших диапазонов, не замечая проблемы.

Comment: не понял, а какое отношение проверка попадения в диапазон имеет отношение к вычислению суммы? И в каком случае получается неверный результат интересно?

Comment: @dzhioev: (1) посмотрите на заголовок вопроса, чтобы понять в каком контексте код читается (2) подумайте чем целые числа от чисел с плавающей точкой отличаются в Питоне.

Comment: (1) способ вычисления суммы к основному вопросу не имеет отношения, у нас тут уже оффтопик обсуждение идет (2) я прекрасно знаю, чем числа с плавающей точкой отличаются от целых. Я ведь уже согласился выше , что надо использовать //. Повторяюсь, сразу не обратил внимание, что вопрос про Python 3 (а в Python 2 / делает то же, что // в Python 3).

Comment: (1) я объясняю почему код в моём ответе на вопрос  "диапазон ввода чисел", а не какой-то другой вопрос, содержит `sum(range(a, b+1))` вместо простой и эффективной формулы, которую Гаусс (по легенде) чуть ли не в три года вывел. В другом контексте, другие заботы были бы.  (2) вы спросили в каком случае неверный результат, а сами ведь знаете в каком случае ;) То что Вы сперва неверный код привели, только подтверждает правило. Не нужно свысока на простые ошибки смотреть, много-миллиардные проекты проваливаются из-за простых ошибок.

Comment: А можно привести примеры расчётов для А=1, В=3, и А=5, В=6. У меня на бумаге, в первом случае 4 получается, а во втором 26.

Comment: В первом случае считаю так: А=1, В=3, А<B, 1<3, Sum=1+3=4; А=А+1=1+1=2, В =В-1=3-1=2, А=В, условие не выполняется, следовательно Sum=4. Во втором случае - А=5, В=8, А<В, 5<8, Sum=5+8=13; А=А+1=5+1=6, В=В-1=8-1=4, А<В, 6<7, Sum=6+7=13; А=А+2=5+2=7, В=В-2=8-2=6, А>В, условие не выполняется, следовательно Sum=13+13=26.

Comment: @Александр: не пытайтесь новый вопрос в комментарии умять. Задайте его как отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос. Явно словами укажите что вы пытаетесь подсчитать. Пример ввода, вывода и что у вас вместо этого получается. Комментарий намекает, что вы не знаете что range() функция делает. Попробуйте поиграться с ней в интерактивной консоли.

Comment: Всё верно, я на Яве пишу, но к сожалению не понимаю условий задачи, гугление привело сюда, потому здесь и спрашиваю, т.к. хочу понят алгоритм.

Comment: Гугление функции range() привело к понятию, что это цикл. Но это не помогло мне понять условия задачи.

Comment: Это не имеет отношения к текущему вопросу о том как проверить диапазон введённых чисел в Питоне. Следуйте рекомендациям в моём предыдущем комментарии. Справа вверху на странице есть кнопка: "задать вопрос"